# Parsing a JSON request in c# with a c# keyword

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON rpc 2.0 request. The standard is defined [here](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification).

I've defined my class as:

```
 [DataContract]
     public class JsonRpc2Request
     {
         public string method;
         [DataMember(Name = "params")]
         public object parameters;
         public object id;
     }
```

I then try and parse a request as follows:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var obj = ser.Deserialize<JsonRpc2Request>(Message.Trim());
```

`obj.parameters` is always `null`. I think this is because I can't define an object with the name `params` as per the JSON RPC spec. (My attempt is using the `[DataMember(Name="params")]` decoration.

How can I populate my parameters object when the JSON RPC spec calls for the name `params` which is a keyword in c#?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx):

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonRpc2Request));
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Message.Trim()));

var obj = ser.ReadObject(stream);
```

and you'll want to annotate `method` and `id` with the `DataMember` attribute as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to get the full control over serialization/deserialization process

```
string json = @"{""method"":""mymethod"",""params"":[1,2],""id"":3}";
var rpcReq = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonRpc2Request>(json);


public class JsonRpc2Request
{
    [JsonProperty("method")]
    public string Method;

    [JsonProperty("params")]
    public object[] Parameters;

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id;
}
```

Since after completing this step, you are going to have to deal with more complex cases like

```
 @"{""method"":""mymethod"",""params"":[{""name"":""joe""}],""id"":3}";
```